# How to save the state of a service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-intentservice

I've created a `GeoService extends Service` and implemented `onLocationChanged` callback.

I also have three different Intent Services which are designed to process location data.

I want to pass intents with actions to my `GeoService` , and based on these intents corresponding Intent Services should be run or not run in `onLocationChanged`.

E.g. if I pass `ACTION_A_START`, `ACTION_B_START`, `ACTION_C_START` three Intent services should be run each time `onLocationChanged` is triggered.
When I pass `ACTION_B_STOP`, two Intent services should run.

How to restore this behavior after service is destroyed and restarted?

`START_REDELIVER_INTENT` will restore only my last intent (with `ACTION_B_STOP`).
`ACTION_A_START` and `ACTION_C_START` will be ignored.

P.S. I use `SharedPreferences` at the moment, but I don't like this solution..

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411744/android-when-a-service-is-killed-how-can-we-persist-the-service-state-for-late

Comment: GreenDAO is a super maintainable/efficient ORM solution (like an SQLite wrapper) for Android.  Once integrated, I find it a very useful alternative to `SharedPreferences` since it enforces a more rigid data structure. http://greenrobot.org/greendao/